# VBScript: How to add a HEX value into a registry key?

Tags: vbscript, registry

binary data to insert(from .reg file):

"FailureActions"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
  00,01,00,00,00,60,ea,00,00,01,00,00,00,60,ea,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

MSDN says: "RegWrite will write at most one DWORD to a REG_BINARY value. Larger values are not supported with this method."

wshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Service1\FailureActions", hexValueHere, "REG_BINARY"

I am trying to avoid calling Regedit and importing a .reg file. I just need to add "FailureActions" key with the proper hex value mentioned above.

Any ideas? Here is my latest code which is still NOT working. :-(

```
Option Explicit
Call SetServiceFailureActions()

Sub SetServiceFailureActions()
    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

    Set objRegistry=GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    "." & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    Dim path
    path = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Service1\FailureActions"

    Dim hexValues, arrHexValues, arrDecValues
    hexValues = "hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,60,ea,00,00,01,00,00,00,60,ea,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00"

    arrHexValues = Split(Replace(hexValues, "hex:", ""), ",")
    arrDecValues = DecimalNumbers(arrHexValues)

    Dim objRegistry, Return
    Return = objRegistry.SetBinaryValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, "FailureActions", arrDecValues)

    If (Return = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) Then
        Wscript.Echo "Registry key value for [FailureActions] has been added successfully."
    Else
        ' An error occurred
        Wscript.Echo "ERROR when setting the value for the registry key: [FailureActions]."
        WScript.Echo "Exception:" & vbCrLf &_
                     "Error number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf &_
                     "Error description: '" & Err.Description & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub


Function DecimalNumbers(arrHex)
   Dim i, strDecValues
   For i = 0 to Ubound(arrHex)
     If isEmpty(strDecValues) Then
       strDecValues = CLng("&H" & arrHex(i))
       'WScript.Echo "strDecValues: " & strDecValues
     Else
       strDecValues = strDecValues & "," & CLng("&H" & arrHex(i))
       'WScript.Echo "strDecValues: " & strDecValues
     End If
   next
   DecimalNumbers = split(strDecValues, ",")
End Function
```

Thank you

Comment: Your array must be a collection of _decimal values_, not hex, as explained [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/24/how-can-i-write-binary-data-to-the-registry.aspx)

Comment: that explains. Thank you again!

Comment: It still didn't work after I converted to decimals :-(, I will do some more research and will post a new question. It may be something silly I am missing. Thanks

Comment: The sample code at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I used as a template doesn't work either

Comment: I found this article but it still didnt work! http://forums.petri.com/showthread.php?t=46158

Comment: Check my latest updated code :-) - I dont know what else to do. So frustrating.

Comment: Seems to be a problem writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, I've updated my "answer" :(

Comment: Thanks bud. I will just use the RegEdit.exe command. It is unbelievable how MSDN docs are bad written. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Too late maybe, but I found out the answer - because that's a 'protected key' in the Registry, the script must be run in an elevated process..

Comment: weird I was running as Admin. (Run as...). But we finished the script and ended up using SC.EXE which fit all our needs. Thank you so much Stuart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the WMI Registry Provider's SetBinaryValue method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393286(v=vs.85).aspx), as long as you don't have to support Windows XP: however note that **this must run as an elevated process as it's a protected key**:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE    = &H80000002
Set objRegistry = GetObject("Winmgmts:root\default:StdRegProv")

path = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Service1"
values = Array(128,81,1,0,0,0,0,0) ' etc

Return = objRegistry.SetBinaryValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _
   path, "FailureActions", values)

If (Return = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) Then
    Wscript.Echo "Binary value added successfully"
Else
    ' An error occurred
End If
```

Comment: I am getting: C:\temp\SetServiceOptions.vbs(13, 5) SWbemObjectEx: Invalid parameter

Comment: You could edit your question to include the SetServiceOptions script, or ask a new one: without seeing the code, it's impossible to see why you're getting that error.